# NavigationExperimental replace scene with animation

Tags: animation, navigation, react-native, stack

Its way to replace last scene in stack with newone? Like new scene is pushed with animation and older is silently poped from stack when push animation end. NavigationExperimental StateUtils replaceAt and replaceAtIndex only change scene on top without animation.

Comment: What renderer are you using? Are using the navigation card stack or the navigation transitioner?

Comment: I use default card stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is no utility function in `NavigationStateUtils` that does this for you but what you have to do is [`push`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3a8c302ae815be0a9b1a6d14860ff8186d43fc07/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L59-L74) and then at the very end of the navigation transition animation you do a [`reset`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3a8c302ae815be0a9b1a6d14860ff8186d43fc07/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L186-L212) with all the routes except the route before the newest one.

Since you're using `NavigationCardStack`, you have to do the [`reset`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3a8c302ae815be0a9b1a6d14860ff8186d43fc07/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationStateUtils.js#L186-L212) on the component that you're pushing using `InteractionManager` because [`NavigationCardStack` does not have a callback prop to call when the transition is finished](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0cf95056303b8690077ae8aa842f4d810bf3cbc9/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStack.js#L129-L189).

Here's an example:

```
// Navigation reducer
function routeReducer(
  navigationState = {
    routes: [],
    index: 0,
  },
  action,
) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'replaceWithPushAnimation':
      // Pass a `reset` flag to your component so it knows to `resetWithoutRoute`
      return NavigationStateUtils.push(navigationState, action.route);
    case 'resetWithoutRoute':
      return NavigationStateUtils.reset(
        navigationState,
        [
          // Copy of all the routes except for navigationState.routes[length - 2]
        ]);
    default:
      return navigationState;
  }
}

// The component that you pushed
class PushedComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.shouldResetWithoutPrevious) {
      // This runs after the navigation transition is over
      InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        // This function calls the reducer to trigger the
        // routes reset
        this.props.onNavigate({
          type: 'resetWithoutRoute',
        });
      });
    }
  }
  // render() {}
}
```

If you don't like this approach, you can use `NavigationTransitioner`, which [has a `onTransitionEnd` callback prop](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/85a6f011b6e4d9f86bc82437c88273f4cc2782d3/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationTransitioner.js#L67-L73) to do the `reset`, however, because it's a lower-level API, you have to implement the navigation transitions yourself.

Comment: where do you make this value as true in your code this.props.shouldResetWithoutPrevious, show that time too @rclai